# Why isn't the MySQLi search engine working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble taking off the section option i don't want the 10, 20, 50 option to be there, so i took out the following codes:

```
 <select name="results"> 
    <option>10</option> <option>20</option> <option>50</option> </select>
```

and

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['results'])
```

but once i did the search engine stopped working anyone know why?

here is  the original code:

```
<form action="/search.php" method="GET"> 


<input type="text" name="term" size="50"> 
<select name="results"> 
<option>10</option> <option>20</option> <option>50</option> </select>
<input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>




<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'searchengine');

    if(!$db) {
        die('sorry we are having some problbems');
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query(
        $db,
        sprintf(
            "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,%d",
            '%'. mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['term']) .'%',
            mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['results'])
        )
    );

    while($ser = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<h2><a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[pageurl]</a></h2>";
    }

    mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: So it works as it is, but when you removed the `select` stuff, it stops working. Can you post the non-working code? Might be a simple syntax error.

Comment: What's the error you're getting (if any)? What's the current code?

Comment: i posted the original code with it.

Comment: You posted the *working* code. Show us what's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you removed **exactly** what you said you removed and only that, your removal of the `mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['results'])` declaration will make your query invalid.

To get it working again, you need to touch up your query:

```
$sql = mysqli_query(
        $db,
        sprintf(
            "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,20",
            '%'. mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['term']) .'%'
        )
    );
```

Make sure your `LIMIT` is set to your liking, as you won't have the option to change it at runtime now that you've removed that option selection from your code.

Comment: @user3618941 If so, please mark it as "Accepted" (green check mark) to ensure future visitors will be able to see it clearly.